# Laravel | Get value of a column with

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-5

i am having a problem with laravel, all the details are given below.

I Have 2 tables in mysql database : books & pens.

books & pens have columns : bookid,bookname & penid,penname, respectively.

Users have a transactions table with : bookid or penid.

I am retrieving all the transactions of a specific user with this:

```
$usertransactions = $user->usertransactions;
```

Not to worry about the relationships between user and usertransaction model, its all setup.

the response of the function above is:

```
"data": {

    "Id": "1",
    "Bookid": "27",

}
```

or

```
"data": {

    "Id": "2",
    "Penid": "42",

}
```

I want the result to be like below:

```
"data": {

    "Id": "1",
    "Bookid": "27",
    "Bookname" : "bookname from books table using the Bookid from response"

}
```

I Would appreciate the help.

Regards

Comment: have you a relationship between `usertransaction` and `book` models ?

Comment: yes , all the relationship of models is already setup everything is working fine, i can not find a way to get the bookname using bookid from response from books table

Answer (score 1):

first of all, the common practice of naming columns is `snake_case`. so it is better to name `bookid` as `book_id`. and also for your relations and function names, it is good to keep it `CamelCase`. so instead of `usertransactions` it is better to write `userTransactions`.

Let's get back to your question. Since you have book_id in your response, you should be able to build a relationship between `UserTransaction` and `Book` models. in `Book model`:

```
public function userTransactions() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(UserTransaction::class); //it can be one to many or many to many base on your logic. I assume Many to many
}
```

then you should define the reverse relationship in `UserTransaction model`:

```
public function books(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Book::class);
}
```

now you can load all books object using `load` method like `$usertransactions = $user->usertransactions->load('books')`

if you want your response match exactly then use `https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-resources` as @Maraboc has mentioned.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You are working with a many to many relation.

Check out this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

So in your code it could be:

return $this->belongsToMany('App\Book', 'transactions', 'user_id', 'book_id');

Use select or pluck to format your data if required.

Comment: i don’t think you understood my question mate. theres nothing to be changed in the model files , its in the controller file. i need a statement which can get the transaction and then get the id from the response it got and using that id it gets the name of the book from books table.

Comment: I don't think you understood the MVC framework. Check Peyman's answer. We both are telling you to use belongsToMany method in your model. It's because not everything needs to go into the controller's file. Some methods must go into the model's file. And also, you should show your code of $user->usertransactions;

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you want using the [Eloquent: API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-resources) :

You have to create a Usertransaction resource, assuming you have a one to one relationship between Usertransaction and Book models :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class Usertransaction extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'Bookid' => $this->book->bookid,
            'Bookname' => $this->book->bookname 
        ];
    }
}
```

Finally in the controller you can do this :

```
use App\Usertransaction;
use App\Http\Resources\Usertransaction as UsertransactionResource;

function YourMethod() {
    $usertransactions = $user->usertransactions;
    return UsertransactionResource::collection($usertransactions);
}
```

PS : you can do the same for pens :)

Comment: in some cases more than 1 transactions are received , will this work with them too? & do you mind telling me how does the resource class you made determines book as a model without importing it using use command at top? , "$this->book->bookid" , i am sorry i am not familiar with resources.

Comment: For the first question yes it will, because we assume it's a collection `Usertransaction::collection`, for the second question it's not a model that need import because i's just a relationship so no need for import, but you need to name your relation in the Usertransaction model book or rename the the book in this statment `$this->book->bookname` with the name of your relationship :)

Comment: BadMethodCallException

Comment: witch method ??

Comment: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::collection()

Comment: Aaah sorry my mistake it's `UsertransactionResource::collection` not `Usertransaction::collection` check the updated answer :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177158/discussion-between-maraboc-and-amir-qureshi).